# How to pass json object in jmeter using csv file?

Tags: jmeter

This is the json object

```
{  
   "addLabourerToSpecificShift":false,
   "isEarlySubmit":true,
   "isExistinglabourer":false,
   "task":"add",
   "currentDate":"2018-06-08T07:08:21.296Z",
   "allSections":[  

   ],
   "labourerBean":{  
      "gender":0,
      "enrolmentDate":"2018-06-08T07:08:21.296Z",
      "epfMemberId":"2",
      "firstName":"Kedar",
      "lastName":"jadhav",
      "dob":"1990-11-30T18:30:00.000Z",
      "phone1":"1236547896",
      "panNumber":"1452368545"
   },
   "companyRetentionBonus":0,
   "isRootAdmin":true,
   "from":"manage_labourers"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be formatting your JSON payload to look like a single string i.e.

```
{"addLabourerToSpecificShift":false,"isEarlySubmit":true,"isExistinglabourer":false,"task":"add","currentDate":"2018-06-08T07:08:21.296Z","allSections":[],"labourerBean":{"gender":0,"enrolmentDate":"2018-06-08T07:08:21.296Z","epfMemberId":"2","firstName":"Kedar","lastName":"jadhav","dob":"1990-11-30T18:30:00.000Z","phone1":"1236547896","panNumber":"1452368545"},"companyRetentionBonus":0,"isRootAdmin":true,"from":"manage_labourers"}
```

Then you will be able either to use [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) with `\n` Delimiter like:

[image: JMeter CSV Data Set Config]

and refer the value as `${json}` where required.

Even easier option would be using [__StringFromFile()](https://www.blazemeter.com/ja/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) function directly in your [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler `Body Data` tab like:

```
${__StringFromFile(/path/to/your/csv/file,,,)}
```

[image: JMeter StringFromFile]

[__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) function reads the next line from the specified file each time it's being called so this way you will be able to parameterise your request with minimal effort